# Python - Psycopg2, how to mix tuples and strings in cur.execute()?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new to Python and Psycopg2... I'am trying to do a query that uses `IN` sql statement and other `WHERE` clauses but I'm getting an error like this:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: argument formats can't be mixed
```

From what I understand I'm mixing a Python tuple with strings, here is the `SELECT` statement:

```
cur2.execute("SELECT hash FROM jobsads_text\
                     WHERE\
                     date_inserted::timestamp::date - now()::timestamp::date <= 0\
                     AND date_inserted::timestamp::date - now()::timestamp::date >= -7\
                     AND hash NOT IN %s \
                     AND lower((%s)) LIKE '%(%s)%'\
                     ORDER BY date_inserted asc;", ((not_in_sql,), search_field, search_string))
```

I get error in the query above.

This query bellow runs OK:

```
cur2.execute("SELECT hash FROM jobsads_text\
                     WHERE\
                     date_inserted::timestamp::date - now()::timestamp::date <= 0\
                     AND date_inserted::timestamp::date - now()::timestamp::date >= -7\
                     AND hash NOT IN %s \
                     ORDER BY date_inserted asc;", (not_in_sql,))
```

My question is... How can I mix the tuple `not_in_sql` with the strings `search_field` and `search_string`?

Any clues?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = (1, 3)
search_field = 'c'
search_string = '%something%'
print cursor.mogrify("""\
    select * 
    from p
    where 
        c in %%s
        and
        lower (%s) like %%s
    """ % search_field, (t, search_string))
```

Will output this:

```
select * 
from p
where 
    c in (1, 3)
    and
    lower (c) like '%something%'
```

psycopg2 will not substitute identifiers like column names so you must substitute then before passing the query as the first argument of the method.